# Can't convert from string to smalldatetime value

Tags: c#, sql

This is my statement that throws `Exception` saying

> Can't convert from string to smalldatetime value

How do I fix it or write the correct statement?

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT name,[build-id],exitTime,enterTime,tagType FROM Employees,GateLogging WHERE GateLogging.tagType='Employee' AND enterTime=DATEDIFF(minute,GateLogging.enterTime,GETDATE())>10", MyConn);
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `WHERE` clause, remove the single quotes around the `DATEDIFF(minute,GateLogging.enterTime,GETDATE())>10` statement.

**EDIT**

You're also comparing a datetime field against what I'd call a boolean. Remove the `enterTime=`. Your statement should look like this:

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT name,[build-id],exitTime,enterTime,tagType FROM Employees,GateLogging WHERE GateLogging.tagType='Employee' AND DATEDIFF(minute,GateLogging.enterTime,GETDATE())>10", MyConn);
```

**EDIT 2**

Your table definition is as follows:

```
tagID bigint
enterTime nchar(10) 
exitTime nchar(10) 
date nchar(10)
```

Of course, `enterTime` can not be used in `DATEDIFF`, as it is not a `DATETIME`.

Question: Why are you storing dates and times as NCHAR(10) instead of `DATETIME`? That's not good style!

Solution 1: Change `enterTime` and `exitTime` to `DATETIME` and you're fine.

Solution 2: Change your statement, so that you convert `enterTime` to a valid `DATETIME`. I assume that `enterTime` only contains the time of day, so you'd have to mix in the date part before converting.

**EDIT 3**

Assuming that `date` stores the day in format `yyyymmdd` and `enterTime` stores the time in format `hh:mm:ss`, you'll be able assemble a `DATETIME`:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(date, 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(date, 5, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(date, 7,2) + ' ' + entryTime, 102)
```

So your statement from above would look like:

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter(
     "SELECT name,[build-id],exitTime,enterTime,tagType 
      FROM Employees,GateLogging 
      WHERE GateLogging.tagType='Employee' AND
      DATEDIFF(minute,CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(date, 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(date, 5, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(date, 7,2) + ' ' + entryTime, 102),GETDATE())>10", MyConn);
```

In case the date/time format stored in the fields of your database are different, you'll have to adjust the `SUBSTRING` statements within the `CONVERT()` accordingly.

Comment: but i alredy do that but still has the same exception

Comment: @sama: Please do not edit the original post to reflect changes suggested in answers. This renders the answer invalid. The first parts of my and TheVillageIdiot's answers will now seem incorrect, as the single quotes that were there when we answered are gone now.

Comment: i do that but it throw the"Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string." exception

Comment: Post table definition please.

Comment: this is the table definition
tagID bigint 

enterTime  nchar(10) 
exitTime nchar(10) 
date nchar(10)

Comment: enterTime is not of type DATETIME, so it can't be used in the DATEDIFF function. What's the point in storing a DateTime in a nchar(10) column anyways?

Comment: The question, by the way, should not be tagged "C#", but "SQL", as your problem clearly is not in the C# code but in your SQL Table definition (in my opinion) or in the query string, in case you want to keep the column data type.

Comment: but i can't change the types of entertime and exittime in the table
it say can't be changed

Answer (score 1):

First thing you were putting DATEDIFF stuff in quotes (') and comparing it with enterTime which I suspect is smalldatetime type so you got the error. Correct SQL will be:

```
  SELECT name,[build-id],exitTime,enterTime,tagType 
  FROM Employees,
  GateLogging 
  WHERE 
      GateLogging.tagType='Employee'
  AND
      enterTime = DATEDIFF(minute,GateLogging.enterTime,GETDATE())
```

As for your >10 I think you should not compare it with enterTime but use this instead:

```
    SELECT name,[build-id],exitTime,enterTime,tagType
    FROM Employees,
    GateLogging 
    WHERE 
    GateLogging.tagType='Employee'
    AND
    DATEDIFF(minute,GateLogging.enterTime,GETDATE()) >10
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd also not for you that you're not using ANSI style join syntax - this might cause you a few problems in later life.